# Convergence of a series with sin term

Tags: real-analysis

I need to show that the series

$\sum{\frac{1}{n}\sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}}) $

is convergent.

I know that the sine term is $0$ for even $n,$ $1$ when $n$ is $1,5,9, \ldots$ and $-1$ when $n$ is $3,7,11, \ldots$ so it's probably a good idea to use the Alternating Series Test, but I'm struggling to find away to translate this into the problem

Answer (score 1):

What you did shows that your series is equal to the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{2n-1}$. And now, yes, you can apply the alternating series test.